# Inflating RecyclerView in DialogFragment IllegalStateException

Tags: android, dialog, android-recyclerview

I need to put a recycler view in a dialog, so I do this:

```
public class RecyclerTemperatureFragment extends DialogFragment
{
String[] items = {getString(R.string.kt),getString(R.string.mph),getString(R.string.kmh)};
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerTemperatureAdapter adapter;

public static RecyclerTemperatureFragment newInstance()
{
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    RecyclerTemperatureFragment fragment = new RecyclerTemperatureFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    return dialog;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_temperature, container, false);

  recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recTemperature);
  adapter = new RecyclerTemperatureAdapter(getActivity(),items);
  recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
  recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getActivity()));
  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

  getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

  return rootView;
}
}
```

and in my class at OnClickListener event of my button, I do this:

```
  public class TrueAirSpeedFragment extends Fragment
  {
   TextView casTW, paTW, satTW, ins, clc,casUM,paUM,satUM;
   ImageView calculate;
   EditText casET, paET, satET;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 //this works
}
private void setUpCASUM(final TextView textview)
{
    RecyclerTemperatureFragment dialog = RecyclerTemperatureFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    dialog.show(manager,"DTAG");
}
```

}

but when I launch it I get this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment RecyclerTemperatureFragment{b4d74cd} not attached to Activity
                  at android.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:819)
                  at android.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:841)
```

how could I solve this problem? I followed a tutorial on the web, but in the video this code works but in my project it crashes.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is probabbly giving error, because to get Resources you need context:

```
String[] items = {getString(R.string.kt),getString(R.string.mph),getString(R.string.kmh)};
```

Try initiating items in `onCreate`